# How to view PDF from Firebase Storage - SwiftUI PDFVIEW

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, pdfkit

I am having some issues trying to display a PDF which is stored in Firebase Storage in my SwiftUI app.

I have successfully done the following;

- Uploaded a PDF file to Firebase Storage
- Get the `URL` from the directory path
- Create a `PDFView` and pass the `URL`

Currently the `PDFKITVIEW` appears but with nothing to show, and no errors. What am I missing ?

**Show PDFKITVIEW**

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDoc) {
    PDFKitView(path: model.object.docURL) // Path to firebase storage is correct 
}
```

**PDFKITVIEW**

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct PDFKitView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    private var url: URL?
    
    init(path: String) {
        
        // Get url from path
        let dm = DataManager()
        url = dm.urlForDocPath(path: path)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()

        if let url = url {
            pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
        }
        
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        // Empty
    }
    
}
```

**DataManager**

```
func getURLFromFirestore(path: String, success:@escaping (_ docURL:URL)->(),failure:@escaping (_ error:Error)->()){
    
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: path)
     storage.downloadURL { (url, error) in
         if let _error = error{
             print(_error)
             failure(_error)
         } else {
             if let docURL = url {
                 success(docURL)
             }
         }
     }
}

func urlForDocPath(path: String) -> URL? {
    var url: URL?
    
    getURLFromFirestore(path: path,  success: { (docURL) in
        url = docURL
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
    
    return url
}
```

Comment: PDFDocument uses own URL session, so what about authentication/keys/tickets for Firestore? PDFDocument works with URL as with direct open resources. So I assume Firestore just do not allow to access your PDF document, silently. I think you have download document to local filesystem and show it in PDFView from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot post this as a comment since I haven't got enough reputation to do so but seems like the problem can be in your urlForDocPath function, which tries to do an async operation but returning synchronously.

Could you check if url is not nil on the PDFKitView? Because if it is, it will prove my point.

Didn't tried yet in Xcode but needs to be something like following:

```
func urlForDocPath(path: String, success: @escaping (_ docURL:URL?)->(), failure: @escaping (_ error:Error)->()) {
    var url: URL?

    getURLFromFirestore(path: path,  success: { (docURL) in
        success(docURL)
    }) { (error) in
        failure(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it seems that the url was a nil value, and the `urlForDocPath` is a async task. I simply put all the methods in my `ViewModel` and executed the task before presenting the `PDFVIEW` which directly used the `url` property from my model.

Comment: glad you have fixed it.